# .bat file to create a Library with icon in Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, batch, batch-file

Is it possible to create a `.bat` file that creates a Library with an icon in Windows 7 and 8. Of course this can be done by following the already created tutorials online like [Change Your Windows 7 Library Icons the Easy Way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6326/change-your-windows-7-library-icons-the-easy-way/). I would like to teach my colleagues how to do it but a few of them won't try it at all. This is necessary to create a corporate library for our company in the personal laptops of the employees.

Note that this is an idea inspired similar to the icons created like when you install SkyDrive but more inclined to the Library area of Windows.

> **Question**: What command would create a new Library in Windows 7?

Any help rendered will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Library in cmd (and batch) using `shlib.exe`, which comes with Windows SDK.

```
Usage: shlib.exe SUBCOMMAND

Displays and modifies the attributes of Shell Libraries.

Supported commands:
  create      Creates a library at the specified path.
  info        Prints info about the given library.
  enum        Enumerates the folders in the library.
  setattrib   Modifies the attributes of the library.
  add         Adds the specified folder to the specified library.
  remove      Removes the specified folder from the library.
  setsaveloc  Sets the default save location of the library.
  resolve     Resolves the specified folder in the library.
  resolveall  Resolves all locations in the library in bulk.
  manage      Displays the Manage Library Dialog for the library.
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more MSDN info and for download link.
Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/28/10343980.aspx) for short/old example.
Also searching smtg like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmd+create+library) could help you.

Hope it helps!